# Printing request and response headers when crawling with Python

Tags: python, python-requests, web-crawler

I recently got blocked on some websites when I repeatedly crawled them. I have set cron job on AWS lambdas. Crawler runs every hour.

This is the error that I got:

```
url = "https://www.truttikon.ch/publikationen"

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.truttikon.ch', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /publikationen (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd118474690>, 'Connection to www.truttikon.ch timed out. (connect timeout=20)'))
```

Is there a way to print what parameters am I sending to the website when I'm sending requests, or what "trace" do I leave?
I know that I can print headers like this, but I'm getting error in the first line of code.

```
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.headers)
```

I have found something on the web that looks like this, but I do not know what is the difference:

```
response = requests.head(url)
print(response.headers)
```

Is there any way to print full request headers and response headers?

Comment: you can check responses, status codes, and more. here's the [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content)

Comment: I can not, my error is in this line: response = requests.get(url) . I can not print anything

Answer (score -1):

you can check responses, status codes, and more. here's the [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content)

for example:

```
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.status_code)
```

you can also pass custom headers to your request. here's the [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) for that.

```
url = "https://www.truttikon.ch/publikationen"
headers = {'user-agent': 'Skywalker'}
response  = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: I can not, I'm getting an error when I want to send request, in this line: response  = requests.get(url, headers=headers) Im getting an error that I mentioned above